# Cannot convert an ArrayList with my custom object as its data type into the corresponding regular array

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist, classcastexception

As the title says, I cannot convert my `ArrayList` into an `Array`. The data type of my `ArrayList` **is** a custom object but I cannot seem to find what my problem is. The error that it gives doesn't show up as a problem until the program is run. The first two classes are the objects, then I have a class calle `Tester` where the main method is.

Class where error appears:

```
package backend;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Function {

Coefficient[] coefArray;
int constant;

public Function(ArrayList<Coefficient> coefFunction, int constant){
    Coefficient[] coefArray = (Coefficient[]) coefFunction.toArray();
    this.coefArray = sortArray(coefArray);
    this.constant = constant;
}

private Coefficient[] sortArray(Coefficient[] newArray){
    int tempPow = -1000000000;
    Coefficient[] sortedArray = new Coefficient[newArray.length];
    sortedArray = null;
    for(int i=0; isFull(sortedArray); i++){
        for(Coefficient coef : newArray){
            if(coef.pow>tempPow){
                tempPow = coef.pow;
                sortedArray[i] = coef;
            }
        }
    }
    return sortedArray;
}

private boolean isFull(Coefficient[] anArray){
    for(Coefficient i : anArray) {
        if(i == null) return true;
      }
     return false;
}

public String toString(){
    String compiledString="";
    for(Coefficient coef : coefArray){
        compiledString += coef.toString()+"+";
    }
    if(constant==0){
        //No constant there
    }else{
        compiledString = compiledString + constant;
    }
    return compiledString;
}
}
```

Coefficient Class:

```
package backend;

public class Coefficient {

String stringVersion;
public int pow;
public int coefInteger;
public double coefDouble;

//Constructor for variable with a coefficient that is non-fractal and a power higher than 1
public Coefficient(int coef, int pow){
    this.coefInteger = coef;
    this.pow = pow;
    switch(coef){
        case 0:
            //Do nothing here
        case 1:
            this.stringVersion = "x^"+pow;
            break;
        default:
            this.stringVersion = coef+"x^"+pow;
            break;
    }
}

//Constructor for variable with a coefficient that is fractal and a power higher than 1
public Coefficient(double coef, int pow){
    this.coefDouble = coef;
    this.pow = pow;
    this.stringVersion = coef+"x^"+pow;
}

//Constructor for variable with a coefficient but no power
public Coefficient(double coef){
    this.coefDouble = coef;
    this.pow = 1;
    this.stringVersion = coef+"x";
}

//Constructor for variable with a coefficient but no power
public Coefficient(int coef){
    this.coefInteger = coef;
    this.pow = 1;
    this.stringVersion = coef+"x";
}

public String toString(){
    return stringVersion;
}
}
```

Tester:

```
package backend;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tester {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Coefficient> function = new ArrayList<Coefficient>();
    Coefficient xVal;
    Function printFunction;
    System.out.println("Enter the degree of the equation:");
    int pow = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the x components of the function in the order of coefficient then power. Enter constant last:");
        double coef = 0;
        while(pow>0){
            coef = scan.nextDouble();
            if(pow==1){
                if((int) coef == coef){
                    xVal = new Coefficient((int) coef);
                }else{
                    xVal = new Coefficient(coef);
                }
            }else{
                if((int) coef == coef){
                    xVal = new Coefficient((int) coef, pow);
                }else{
                    xVal = new Coefficient(coef, pow);
                }
            }
            function.add(xVal);
            pow--;
        }

        System.out.println("Enter the constant:");
        printFunction = new Function(function, scan.nextInt());
        System.out.println(printFunction.toString());


}
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object;
cannot be cast to [Lbackend.Coefficient;
at backend.Function.<init>(Function.java:11)
at backend.Tester.main(Tester.java:36)
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. If you see something else that needs to be fixed, please point it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in this line:

```
Coefficient[] coefArray = (Coefficient[]) coefFunction.toArray();
```

If you read the javadoc of [`toArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray--), you can see that it returns an `Object[]`, which you cannot simply cast to `Coefficient[]`.

Instead use [`toArray(T[] a)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray-T:A-):

```
Coefficient[] coefArray = coefFunction.toArray(new Coefficient[coefFunction.size()]);
```

Disclaimer: I did not review the rest of your code, so the absence of any remarks does not imply that everything else is fine.